# React Native - Android LayoutAnimation keyboard FlatView Bug

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard, layout-animation

I am currently having an annoying problem with (I think) LayoutAnimation.

My problem is the following, I have an app where I can search throughout my FlatList, with a search button I open the panel and get the focus on the TextInput which open the keyboard. The problem comes when I want to close it for some reason if I close it manually with the back button of the phone It closes and everything is fine same by tapping on the list to close it, but the problem comes when I close the search (so the TextInput is remove from the screen and the keyboard is closed automatically even without calling `.blur()` but I also tried and got the same problem.

Here are some screens to explain : 
[image: List everything is fine]
[image: Keyboard opened]
[image: All the zone that was covered by the keyboard that is now gone is not used anymore for some reason]

Now here is some chunk of the code :

```
 _onPressSearch() {
LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
this.setState({ 
  showSearch: !this.state.showSearch
 }, function () {
  ( this.state.showSearch ? 
    this.refs.searchInput.focus() : 
    this.setState({
      searchString: "",
      filtered: null
    }) )
});
```

}

```
    var searchBar = (this.state.showSearch ?
  <View>
    <TextInput
      style={styles.searchInput}
      ref='searchInput'
      onChangeText={this._onChangeText.bind(this)}
      value={this.state.searchString}
      underlineColorAndroid={Colors.search}
      maxLength={25}
      autoCapitalize='none'
      autoCorrect={false}
      placeholder={I18n.t('search')}
      placeholderTextColor={Colors.search}
      clearButtonMode='never' />
  </View> : <View />);


    <List style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatList
        data={(this.state.filtered === null ? this.state.listings : this.state.filtered)}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        extraData={this.state}
        renderItem={this._renderItem} />
    </List>
```

I am using :

```
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.52.0",
```

which I updated from 0.49.4 to 0.52.0 hoping it would fix the problem but seems not

For information : no problem in IOS, and I did active the animation on android to get the animation.
Furthermore, if I remove the animation `LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();`
everything works except that I don't have animation of course.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer. It appears to be a known issue for which there seems no urgency to resolve. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25832

Comment: I had a similar problem and was able to solve it by enabling react-native-screens. Not sure if it is totally related to your issue, but just in case you can take a look at the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63719002/138392