# React Native LayoutAnimation bug with react navigation?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am handling the keyboard in my app... I have read that the best way to animate it on android is using the LayoutAnimation API, and yeah it works fine but when I navigate back to other screens in which keyboard doesn't appear an unknown View with the same height of my keyboard is shown.

Has anyone experimented with this problem? On iOS it works perfectly, but not on Android.

I have tried to do UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(false); when my component unmounts and this View doesn't appear when going back, but if I open the keyboard again the animation disappears.

Comment: Found someone with same problem: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26551

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had a similar issue when using `LayoutAnimation.configureNext` and `React Navigation 5` on Android. I never found the root cause of the problem, but what solved it for me was enabling `react-native-screens`

Run:

```
# bare React Native project
npm install react-native-screens

# if you use Expo managed workflow
expo install react-native-screens
```

Then place the following code at the top of your root file before rendering any screens:

```
import { enableScreens } from "react-native-screens";

enableScreens();
```

> Note: I am using `Expo SDK 38`, so I'm not sure if this *fix* is applicable in non-Expo environments. Here is a link to the [Expo docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/screens/)

Comment: enableScreens() called automatically when install react-native-screens